# About the history of crystal language / Sobre a história da linguagem Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Good morning / Good afternoon / Good evening,

I'm doing a college work on the Crystal programming language, I looked on the site, wikis etc ... for the history of this language but I did not find much, since part of the work is to create an article that talks about **readability, reliability etc. ..** Would anyone know where I can find such information?

Thank you.

Comment: https://crystal-lang.org/blog/ may be useful (has articles back to whenever) you could also ask questions on the chat or google group

Comment: Crystal history in one sentence: "We love Ruby, but it's so slow..."

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Besides the blog there are some older presentations on [slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/crystallanguage) which detail a lot of background information about the language and its inception.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.